# Performing a WHERE statement or a JOIN ON with a trimmed string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, trim

So I'm trying to join two tables based on a matching field, but some of the entries have white space, either as spaces or tabs. However, when I perform a join on the trimmed field, it doesn't work. Neither of these cases work:

```
Select * FROM dbo.table 
 WHERE replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(**DOCUMENT_ID**)), char(9), '') = 'AB10001'
```

And:

```
Select * FROM dbo.table T1
join dbo.table2 T2
ON replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(**T1.DOCUMENT_ID**)), char(9), '')
 = replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(**T2.DOCUMENT_ID**)), char(9), '')
```

To bypass this, I've even tried wrapping inside a sub-select.

```
Select * FROM (
   Select * FROM dbo.table 
) T
WHERE replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(**T.DOCUMENT_ID**)), char(9), '') = 'AB10001'
```

None of these conditions ever works. Am I missing something about how SQL compiles the query. Due to some technical problems I'm not really in a situation where I can Update with the Trimmed value.

Anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: Please add some data and expected result.

Comment: Tried `WHERE column LIKE '%AB10001%'` ?

Comment: Yeah, of course that works, but it doesn't work on the joins which are more important for the real query I'm writing. I'm more wondering why SQL sub-select on the trimmed string doesn't work so that I can fix the join.

Thanks though!

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen - the result is blank unless I use a LIKE statement, which doesn't work in the case of a join.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and show the data types?  E.g. is the DOCUMENT_ID column a varchar, nvarchar, text, or ntext column?

Comment: It's an nvarchar(80) that was a foreign key in Access but now is a just a normal de-indexed field.

Comment: Really, it's just matching 'AB10001' with '    AB10001' on a JOIN. Which should be really really easy, but I think there's something fishy about the way SQL does JOINs that makes this not work.

Comment: What character do you want to remove? specifically? its only spaces?

Comment: are you sure there are no CHAR(0) chars in there.  LTRIM and RTRIM won't trim that out and they aren't visible.  Also, SQL server handles CHAR(0) very strangley-- `NCHAR(0) = ''` is true whereas `CHAR(0) = ''` is not true in SQL server.

Comment: Yeah - if I do a select on (LTRIM(RTRIM(**T.DOCUMENT_ID**)), char(9), '') I get to see the result and it looks exactly how it should - it just simply doesn't work on the Join.

Comment: `SELECT DOCUMENT_ID, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DOCUMENT_ID) FROM dbo.table WHERE column LIKE '%AB10001%'` to see *exactly* which characters are in there, printable or not. `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` remove only spaces. Not, for example, line feeds, Unicode zero-width breaking spaces and other kinds of funky whitespace that may not be visible on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

So, no definitive answer. I ended up refactoring some of queries into view instead of sub-selects, and that seemed to have done the job.

I suspect that the issue might stem from some mechanism about how the Query Processor works. Debugging that seems way beyond what I want to ever do.

Jereon Mostert suggested to use CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), DOCUMENT_ID) to show all of the possible hidden characters. I ended up just doing a replace against all whitespace chrs posssible.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.DocNumFormatted)), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

Although I suppose there's probably a cleaner regex way to handle that.

Anyway - using a SQL view seemed to do the job. Weird stuff.